# dropdown onchange issue in redux form?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

Below is the redux form example in official site.
[image]

http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/react-widgets/.

If I click the dropdown component and select one item, move the mouse out of the dropdown and release the mouse, the dropdown value will be set Zero like below image.
[image]

How can I fix it, thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your implemented example code?

Comment: hi, you can directly see the bug in http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/react-widgets/.  You can reproduce this bug by drag the value in the 'favorite color' dropdown and drop. I have attached the image 2 here.

Comment: I can reproduce it in the browser, but it's still very hard to debug it when we don't have a better environment to study and change the code. If you could set up the same issue on JSFiddle or something like that then it would be easy to start changing the code to (at least try) to fix the bug.